# Где должен быть главный цикл обработки событий при использовании MVC?

Tags: ооп, mvc, gui

Где должен находиться главный цикл обработки событий? Model, View, Controller? Или может, вообще извне, в мейне? Или в еще одном классе, который инкапсулирует MVC?

Как правильно?

upd:
Отвечая на комментарий, зачем он нужен в MVC: нужен он мне по той причине, что лично я не понимаю, как иначе организовывать логику в MVC и приложениях с GUI вообще.
В моем понимании, где-то в коде должно быть нечто в духе

```
while(true) {
    while(app.EventHappened()) {
        if (app.LastEvent() == App::Event::Click()) { 
            doSomeLogic();    
        }
    }
    app.display();
}
```

В любом случае, полагаю, что так сделать в MVC как минимум можно. Вопрос в том - куда его пихнуть, чтобы было корректно с точки зрения архитектуры.

Comment: А почему, простите, вообще МVС обязательно требует наличия _главного_ цикла обработки событий? Почему, например, каждой модельной компоненте не иметь свой? С другой стороны, почему вообще он нужен? MVC его не предписывает.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос, зачем мне он нужен в MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от многих факторов, никакого предписанного стандарта нет.

Например, если у вас паттерн MVC реализует Web-приложение, то UI (и его внутренние циклы) бежит в браузере у пользователя, а запросы от браузера вполне могут отрабатывать на пуле потоков сервера.

Если у вас обыкновенное десктопное приложение, то да, классические фреймворки требуют единственный «главный» цикл, в котором бежит UI и большая часть контроллера. Модельные компоненты при этом вполне могут иметь собственные циклы сообщений.

Поскольку паттерн MVC не требует цикл сообщений, то он и не налагает требований по его нахождению. В этом случае обычно главный цикл запускает та компонента, которая стартует первой (View или контроллер). Но более чистым подходом, на мой взгляд, будет считать код запуска главного цикла отдельной частью приложения, не являющейся в строгом смысле частью V или C. В любом случае, делайте как вам удобно.